# What is the potential and kinetic energy of the international space station?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, estimation, satellites

I know it's possible to calculate, but what formulas would I use to be as accurate as possible? I'd like to see how it works for something big and high like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As accurate as possible" is a fuzzy concept. Given that you ask this question, I expect that a few simplifying assumptions are justified. For an object in a circular orbit of constant radius $R$, orbiting a perfectly spherical earth of constant density, the kinetic and potential energy can be calculated. Their relationship is beautifully simple, as derived [here](http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~broholm/l24/node1.html):

$$V = -\frac{GMm}{R}$$

$$KE = \frac12 m\omega^2 R^2 = -\frac12 V$$

The height of the ISS varies constantly because of atmospheric drag; it keeps being boosted back up to higher altitude. That effect alone overwhelms most other attempts at accuracy. See this plot [source](http://www.heavens-above.com/IssHeight.aspx):

[image]

Using a mean height of 400 km, and an Earth radius of 6371 km, we find $R=6771\;\rm{km}$. Now all you need is the mass of the ISS (depends on how many people are in it, whether a supply ship has recently docked, etc...). All the other parameters you can easily find on the web.

Note that there are many corrections you might apply - but there are so many gross variables I believe that the above approach is "as accurate as is reasonable".

Comment: Wait, so -GMm/R is the potential energy? Then why is it negative?

Comment: I've calculated it to be about -2.47 x 10^38 (It's in Joules, right? That's the unit of energy)

Comment: Potential energy is taken to be zero at infinity so it is negative everywhere else. And yes the units are J. But your number seems awfully high. Better check your math.